# Intermittent SIGBUS on shared memory segment

Tags: c, shared-memory

I have a server process that allocates a big chunk of memory using the System V XSI shared memory calls (shmget/shmat), from address to 0x500000000 to 0x1d00000000, and then binds it to the first NUMA node.  See pseudocode below (it should be logically correct but might not compile).

The problem is *sometimes* I get a SIGBUS signal when I access the memory, but most of the time I don't.  It works most of the time.  I am using signal handlers to gracefully catch the signals (including SIGSEGV too).

I don't understand why this is flaky.  What can cause SIGBUS erratically?

```
size_t totalSize_ = 96 GiB;
const int flags = IPC_CREAT         // creatE a new shared memory segment
                    | SHM_HUGETLB   // huge pages
                    | SHM_NORESERVE // don't reserve swap space for this.
                    | 0666          // Leave the leading 0 (octal)
                    | SHM_R | SHM_W // These are redundant with 0666
    ;
shmid_ = shmget(key_, totalSize_, flags);

void* desiredBase = 0x0x500000000; 
auto base = shmat(shmid_, desiredBase, 0);

uint32_t mask = 1; // first NUMA node
mbind(base , totalSize_ , MPOL_BIND, &mask, 64, 0) ;
```

And then I do some tests to make sure that the memory is accessible (because of the NUMA binding), by stepping through the address space and calling memcpy every GiB.

```
for(addr = base; addr < last, addr += 1GiB)
   memcpy(addr, "testpattern",10);
```

and then I look for SIGBUS signals.  If NUMA node doesn't have enough huge page memory assigned to it, I get SIGBUS signals. That's fine. However, if I restart the server with the example same code and settings, sometimes it gives me a SIGBUS on the 3rd huge page.  And then I restart it again, and it works fine for all 96 huge pages.  Our system has 100 GiB of huge page memory per NUMA node (4 nodes).

How do I debug this? What log files are useful?  And does it make any sense to add a retry loop on the memcpy until the SIGBUS goes away?

The first part of `/proc/self/maps` looks like this:

```
00400000-01213000 r-xp 00000000 103:07 4986562                           /opt/daemon-0.0.9/bin/daemon
01413000-01415000 r-xp 00e13000 103:07 4986562                           /opt/daemon-0.0.9/bin/daemon
01415000-0141b000 rwxp 00e15000 103:07 4986562                           /opt/daemon-0.0.9/bin/daemon
0141b000-01427000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
01b5d000-01bfa000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
500000000-1d00000000 rwxs 00000000 00:0d 44072961                        /SYSV50420051 (deleted)
2aaac0000000-2aab00000000 rwxp 00000000 00:0d 83594486                   /anon_hugepage (deleted)
7ff9e4000000-7ff9e4021000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
7ff9e4021000-7ff9e8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The `SHM_NORESERVE` among your flags is a likely culprit.  From [the docs for `shmget()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html):

> Do not reserve swap space for this segment.  When swap space is reserved, one has the
> guarantee that it is possible to modify the segment.  When
> swap space is not reserved **one might get `SIGSEGV` upon a
> write if no physical memory is available**.

(Emphasis added)

The fact that the segment creation, binding, and subsequent access *usually* works suggests some kind of contextual effect, such as arising from the amount of physical memory presently available, and a segfault is explicitly among the risks of creating the segment with that flag.

`SIGSEGV` is not exactly the same thing as `SIGBUS`, but the two are generated under similar circumstances.

Comment: There is no indication that there isn't enough physical memory available at the time of the failure.  We've got close to 1TB of RAM on the system, and the shared memory is all huge page memory, which is reserved on boot time and assigned 100 GB per NUMA node, and there is no other process on the machine that uses huge page memory.  We absolutely can not allow this memory be swapped to disk. It must remain resident in physical memory the whole time.

What do you suggest I do if I get a SIGSEGV? Wait and try again?

Comment: @MarkLakata, the `SIGBUS` you get is itself an indication that your memory system is not able to fulfill your write request.  It may be that this reflects an actual flaw in the system (hardware / kernel / standard libraries), and it may be that the issue revolves around something your program does that is not clear from the question (which does not, after all, present a MRE).  But if the flaw is in your code, then the `SHM_NORESERVE` is the only thing among the details that have been presented that seems a plausible explanation for the behavior you describe.

Comment: @MarkLakata, as for what to do if you get a `SIGSEGV`: program behavior is undefined after a signal handler catches a `SIGSEGV` and then returns normally, so my recommendation would be to avoid doing that.  If you catch segfault then, at most, emit a diagnostic and perform *essential* cleanup, to the extent that you can do within the constraints of a signal handler, and then terminate by calling `_exit()`.

Comment: @MarkLakata, I get that your machine is very well provisioned, but the symptoms you describe suggest that your program is pushing it to its limit, and sometimes a little past.